# mypy doesn't understand that the function returns a string

Tags: python, mypy

I have a function that returns a `str` or a specified fallback value (`str` or `None`). When giving a `str` fallback, the function is guaranteed to return a `str`. Running [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy) on this however gives an error.

MWE:

```py
from typing import Any


def f(x: str, fallback: str | None) -> str | None:
    if x.lower() == "yes":
        return "okay"
    return fallback


f("no", fallback="").lower()
```

```
f.py:10: error: Item "None" of "str | None" has no attribute "lower"  [union-attr]
```

How can I tell mypy that it's safe to call `lower()` on the return value of the function?

Comment: [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/typing.html#typing.overload), probably.

Comment: But it's NOT safe if the user omits the parameter.  `mypy` does static analysis, not dynamic analysis.  It's not executing the code as it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from typing import overload


@overload
def f(x: str, fallback: str) -> str:
    ...


@overload
def f(x: str, fallback: str | None = None) -> str | None:
    ...


def f(x: str, fallback: str | None = None) -> str | None:
    if x.lower() == "yes":
        return "okay"
    return fallback


f("no", fallback="").lower()
f("no").lower()
```

(type-)checks out:

- `f("no", fallback="").lower()` is fine (since the fallback is passed in and a string)
- `f("no").lower()` still says `Item "None" of "str | None" has no attribute "lower"`

Of course, if `fallback` is actually `None`, this will return a `None`, so you've broken the pinky-promise your types say.

Answer (score 0):

You need the call to account for the possible null result:

```py
result = f("no", fallback="")

end = result.lower() if result is not None else result
```

Comment: This should not be necessary -- the output is a guaranteed `str`.

Comment: For your input? Sure. For the function call in general it is not

Comment: Right.  That's the point.  `mypy` can't tell this without actually executing the code, and that's not what it does.  That's just one of the limitations of static analysis.  You either suppress the warning, or you add the `None` check.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Optional`

```py
def f(x: str, fallback: Optional[str] = None) -> str | None:
```

Comment: it should be functionally identical ([PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/)), but it may appease mypy

Comment: Well, it doesn't.